# Python Pandas - Difference between groupby keys with repeated valyes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have some data with dates of sales to my clients.
The data looks like this:

|  | Cod client | Items | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 1 | 2022/01/01 |
| 1 | 100 | 7 | 2022/01/01 |
| 2 | 100 | 2 | 2022/02/01 |
| 3 | 101 | 5 | 2022/01/01 |
| 4 | 101 | 8 | 2022/02/01 |
| 5 | 101 | 10 | 2022/02/01 |
| 6 | 101 | 2 | 2022/04/01 |
| 7 | 101 | 2 | 2022/04/01 |
| 8 | 102 | 4 | 2022/02/01 |
| 9 | 102 | 10 | 2022/03/01 |

What I'm trying to acomplish is to calculate the differences beetween dates for each client: grouped first by "Cod client" and after by "Date" (because of the duplicates)

The expected result is like:

|  | Cod client | Items | Date | Date diff | Explain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 1 | 2022/01/01 | NaT | First date for client 100 |
| 1 | 100 | 7 | 2022/01/01 | NaT | ...repeat above |
| 2 | 100 | 2 | 2022/02/01 | 31 | Diff from first date 2022/01/01 |
| 3 | 101 | 5 | 2022/01/01 | NaT | Fist date for client 101 |
| 4 | 101 | 8 | 2022/02/01 | 31 | Diff from first date 2022/01/01 |
| 5 | 101 | 10 | 2022/02/01 | 31 | ...repeat above |
| 6 | 101 | 2 | 2022/04/01 | 59 | Diff from previous date 2022/02/01 |
| 7 | 101 | 2 | 2022/04/01 | 59 | ...repeat above |
| 8 | 102 | 4 | 2022/02/01 | NaT | First date for client 102 |
| 9 | 102 | 10 | 2022/03/01 | 28 | Diff from first date 2022/02/01 |

I already tried doing `df["Date diff"] = df.groupby("Cod client")["Date"].diff()` but it considers the repeated dates and return zeroes for then

**I appreciate for help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can combine several `groupby` operations:

```
# ensure datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# set up group
g = df.groupby('Cod client')

# identify duplicated dates per group
m = g['Date'].apply(pd.Series.duplicated)

# compute the diff, mask and ffill
df['Date diff'] = g['Date'].diff().mask(m).groupby(df['Cod client']).ffill()
```

output:

```
   Cod client  Items       Date Date diff
0         100      1 2022-01-01       NaT
1         100      7 2022-01-01       NaT
2         100      2 2022-02-01   31 days
3         101      5 2022-01-01       NaT
4         101      8 2022-02-01   31 days
5         101     10 2022-02-01   31 days
6         101      2 2022-04-01   59 days
7         101      2 2022-04-01   59 days
8         102      4 2022-02-01       NaT
9         102     10 2022-03-01   28 days
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this, with `transform`:

```
import pandas as pd
# data saved as .csv
df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv", header=0, parse_dates=True)
# convert Date column to correct date.
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
# new column!
df["Date diff"] = df.sort_values("Date").groupby("Cod client")["Date"].transform(lambda x: x.diff().replace("0 days", pd.NaT).ffill())
```